# How can I enable a #define automatically in XCode when the simulator is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a few files that I want compiled differently when I'm testing my iPhone app on the simulator, so I'm using a `#define simulator` macro in those files.  I'm trying to figure out how I can comment out this #define statement and tell XCode to define this macro when the simulator is selected.  How can I do this?

I read a couple other similar questions on here and tried adding a conditional assignment in the "Other C Flags" build settings for the "Any iOS Simulator SDK" architecture with the value set to "-simulator=1", but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` should do the trick.

Comment: it worked great, thank you!  i'll accept your answer in seven minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your own `#define` for this: [Apple provides one for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH19-SW4). Just use

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

around the code you want specific to the simulator. (You'll need to include the `TargetConditionals.h` header for this, but it's probably already included if you import the frameworks.)